# how to reassign javascript event listeners

Tags: javascript

i'm building a web app which allows you to drop HTML elements onto an area.

these elements are built using JS classes with their own properties/methods to customise them.
a user can build a template by selecting elements from the pane and when a new object instance is created they come with a number of event listeners, upto here i understand how to implement it and have done so, but i'm unfamiliar with the concept of how to retain the event listeners after the user saves their template.

for example

lets say i newly created a template, whilst still in the session the browser has all the event listeners but once the template is saved and a new session is created, how do i then get back the event listeners?

**in summary: my goal is to understand how to implement a way to reassign lost event listeners to the elements within the users template without having to re-build them.
**
here is my code:

this calls the new paragraph object

```
const para = document.querySelector('.paragraph');
const head = document.querySelector('.header');

para.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    new Paragraph(container);

});
```

this is the paragraph class

```
class Paragraph{
    constructor(target){
        this.name
        this.id
        this.arrayObjects = []
        this.updateDOM(target);
        this.addEvents();
    }

    updateDOM(target){
        let numOfParas = target.childElementCount || 0;
        this.id = `paragraph${(numOfParas + 1)}`
        let content = `<p id="${this.id}">Text</p>`;
        target.innerHTML += content;
    }

    addEvents(){

        window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if(e.target.id == this.id){
                console.log(document.querySelector(this.id))
                this.updateProperties();
                this.setAllEvents();
            }
        });
    }

    setName(value){
        document.querySelector('#'+this.id).innerText = value
        this.name = value;
    };

    updateProperties(){
        let propertiesPane = document.querySelector('.container-properties');
        propertiesPane.innerHTML = '';
        this.arrayObjects.push(this.UIInput());

        this.arrayObjects.forEach((item) => {
            propertiesPane.innerHTML += item
        });
    };

    setAllEvents(){
        this.setEventInput()
    }

    UIInput(){
        return `<input type="text" id="${'input-'+this.id}">`;
    }

    setEventInput(){
        document.querySelector('#input-'+this.id).addEventListener('keyup', (e) =>{
            //console.log(e)
            this.setName(e.target.value);
        });
    }

}
```

i'm not sure yet how to implement the concept and unable to find any online resource.

i just need the concept of implementation.

Comment: why the rebuilding is a problem? just assign your classes to appropriate elements after a save template is loaded

Comment: thanks for the response, to be honest, it wasn't that the rebuild was an issue, was just hoping to know if there was an easier way of re-linking the class back to the relevant dom element, but i guess i can save the objects properties and then when parsing the template to determine which class to call i could pass the properties to the class. that way even though a new instance was created all the data has been returned.

Comment: yes, that's exactly how it's done